# Using name of vector argument in function

Tags: r

I am writing a function that passes in a vector of values, and I want to use those values for computation within the function. However, I also want to use the name of the vector that I pass to return meaningful error messages but can not figure out how to do so.

My function looks like this

```
func <- function(vector, minimumvalue){
    if(length(vector)==1){
      return(1)}
    else if (length(vector)<minimumvalue){
      stop(paste0("The length of vector is less than ",minimumvalue))}
    else if (length(vector)>minimumvalue){
      stop(paste0("The length of vector is more than ",minimumvalue))}
    else (return(vector))
}
```

My function call looks like this

```
colours <- c("red","green","blue")
func(colours, 2)
```

An returns

> "The length of vector is more than 2", but I would like to say "The
> length of colours is more than 2"

I can achieve this by adding another parameter which passes the name of the vector as a string into the function, but I would like to know if there is a better way to design this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added `deparse(substitute(vector))` to get the name of the object as a string.

```
func <- function(vector, minimumvalue){
  if(length(vector)==1){
    return(1)}
  else if (length(vector)<minimumvalue){
    stop(paste0("The length of ",deparse(substitute(vector))," is less than ",minimumvalue))}
  else if (length(vector)>minimumvalue){
    stop(paste0("The length of ",deparse(substitute(vector))," is more than ",minimumvalue))}
  else (return(vector))
}

colours <- c("red","green","blue")

func(colours, 2)
```

> Error in func(colours, 2) : The length of colours is more than 2

Answer (score 3):

With the `glue` library, you could format the string easier:

```
library(glue)
func <- function(vector, minimumvalue){
    if(length(vector)==1){
      return(1)}
    else if (length(vector)<minimumvalue){
      stop(paste0(glue("The length of vector is less than "),minimumvalue))}
    else if (length(vector)>minimumvalue){
      stop(paste0(glue("The length of {substitute(vector)} is more than "),minimumvalue))}
    else (return(vector))
}

colours <- c("red","green","blue")
func(colours, 2)
```

Output:

```
Error in func(colours, 2) : 
The length of colours is more than 2
```

Or even better to use the `glue` module for formatting `minimumvalue` as well:

```
library(glue)
func <- function(vector, minimumvalue){
    if(length(vector)==1){
      return(1)}
    else if (length(vector)<minimumvalue){
      stop(glue("The length of {substitute(vector)} is less than {minimumvalue}"))}
    else if (length(vector)>minimumvalue){
      stop(glue("The length of {substitute(vector)} is more than {minimumvalue}"))}
    else (return(vector))
}

colours <- c("red","green","blue")
func(colours, 2)
```

The you don't even need `paste0`.